# Google App Engine PHP Session Variable

Tags: php, google-app-engine, session

I am having difficulties with Google App Engine and PHP session variables. I can't seem to access session variables or store them.
This is my code:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login') {
    echo "Session ID:";
    // Never prints the session variable userid
    echo $_SESSION['userid'];

    // Never enters this if statement
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && !empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        echo "Already Logged In";
        exit();
    }
    else {
        // Login with email and password CODE
        // Session variable for userid
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
    }
}
```

The error message:

> ERROR LOG- PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userid

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the logs?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but is your browser accepting the session cookie? Check up on F12 -> Resources -> Cookies -> Your Website.

Comment: @Antiga, Sorry this might be a dumb question, how would I go about checking errors in the logs on the Google App Engine?

Comment: @Dave, I just checked my browser I do see a cookie named: PHPSESSID

Comment: @Antiga, I found the error log: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userid

Comment: Never mind I got it! It should have been $row['userId']. It was case sensitive, completely overlooked it.

Comment: @Alan glad to hear! The logs can be invaluable :).